# How to have two build environments on windows?

Tags: windows, environment-variables, development-environment

I am using windows XP at my office and have set the development environment for building the embedded mobile projects of the company i am working for. I had set up the linux environment using cygwin but after that linux environment works fine, but the command line donot recognise the build commands(build mypath, build  , build link) for my embedded projects. Is there any way to have both the environments working simultaneously ?

Answer (score 0):

CMD or BAT file for fixing your PATH and other environment variable to match the target build environment.

cmd.exe can take a "/k" option to run your BAT file

Desktop shortcut to launch cmd.exe with the /k option start a command shell with the script that configures your environment.